# Slick slider with json code is makes the page slow

Tags: jquery, json, slider, slick.js

slick slider with json not works. When add this code with website, which works, but the entire page took loats of time to load the page

```
        $('.slider').slick({
            dots: false,
            slidesToShow: 7,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 1500,
            variableWidth: true,
            infinite: true,
            initialSlide: 1,
            prevArrow: '<div class="slick-prev"><img src="assets/images/l.png" width="30" /></div>',
            nextArrow: '<div class="slick-next"><img src="assets/images/r.png" width="30" /></div>'
        });


        var x = "https://ic-webreports.herokuapp.com/v2/web-report/feed/180x140";

        $(function () {


            var item = [];

            $.getJSON(x, function (data) {
                $.each(data.item, function (i, f) {
                    var searchRow = "<a href='https://beta.insurercore.com/' target='_blank'><div class='slider-div'><span class='helper'></span><img class='not-img' src='" + f.link + "' /> </div></a>"
                    $('.slider').append(searchRow);
                    $('.slider')[0].slick.refresh();

                });

            });

        });
```